# Does STXXL save the state after crash?

Tags: stxxl

I'm writing a webapp in C++ and would like to use a fast database on SSD.

Seems like STXXL would be faster than other choices (slite,mongodb,...)

Do STXXL's containers keep the data after accidental shutdown (server crash)?
Can the program that was using stxxl be easily restarted from the previous state?